# Aurelia passing data into bindable value of template

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I some template where i'm using `repea.for` some times. There is a problem when I'm trying to bind data into bindable variables inside `<editable-file-upload>` component. 
I want to pass it like `<editable-file-upload elem-id.bind="${elem.parent.id}">Upload</editable-file-upload>` but getting an error -  `aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [app-router] Error: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 7 in [${elem.parent.id}]` . If I'm passing it so `<editable-file-upload elem-id.bind="elem.parent.id">Upload</editable-file-upload>` value is `undefined`. But it can't be undefined, because inside `div.files-wrapper` I'm typyng those values and see right ones. How to pass it? I can't understand.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="someid" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default" repeat.for="elem of elems">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="${elem.parent.id}-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#elems" href="#${elem.parent.id}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#${elem.parent.id}">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i>${elem.parent.kood}
                        </a>

                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="${elem.parent.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="${elem.parent.id}-heading">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="elem" if.bind="!elem.children.length">
                            <div class="files-wrapper">
                                <div class="files-message">Toimingul ei ole veel malle.</div>

                                <editable-file-upload elem-id.bind="${elem.parent.id}">Upload</editable-file-upload>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sub_elems" if.bind="elem.children.length">

                            <div class="sub_elem" repeat.for="subElems of elem.children">

                                <div class="sub_elem-title">${subElem.kood}</div>

                                <div class="files-wrapper">
                                    ${elem.parent.id}
                                    ${subElem.id}
                                    <div class="files-message">Some text</div>

                                    <editable-file-upload elem-id.bind="${elem.parent.id}" sub-elem-id.bind="${subElem.id}">Lae üles</editable-file-upload>


                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `elem-id.bind="${elem.parent.id}"` is not valid syntax in Aurelia. You can do `elem-id="${elem.parent.id}" or `elem-id.bind="elem.parent.id"`. Without seeing the VM for `editable-file-upload`, I can't really say what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inside a `repeat.for` and the property you want access belongs to the parent scope. So, you have to use `$parent` keyword to get to the parent scope and then access the property. For instance:

```
<div class="files-wrapper">
  ${$parent.elem.parent.id}
  ${subElem.id}
  <div class="files-message">Some text</div>

    <editable-file-upload elem-id.bind="$parent.elem.parent.id"
                          sub-elem-id.bind="subElem.id">
     Lae üles
   </editable-file-upload>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $parent isn't necessary any more.

Comment: In all cases? Because I have some cases where I have to use $parent. I think, at least...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't be necessary unless you need to be explicit about which parent scope you want to pull from. Jeremy might contradict me though.

Comment: For example, if both the current scope and the outer scope have a property with the same name?

Comment: I have two answers to that. A) If you only have a single repeater and you have given your repeat variable name the same name as something in the parent scope, then you need to be smacked :-) B) when you're multiple levels deep, it might be okay, and that's where $parent is necessary. But I would avoid it whenever possible just to help the readability of the code.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. And I think your second answer is what is happening in the question. I think OP's `elem` has a collection of `elem`, all properties have the same name. That's why I thought `$parent` was the solution. But it's impossible to be sure without seeing the code, as you said :).

Comment: @FabioLuz Thank you `$parent` helped me to resolve this issue